# elastic beanstalk `bundle exec rails c` can't find gems, rake and other commands can

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I am testing a new deploy on Elastic Beanstalk of a Rails application that is currently deployed on a different provider. The application deploys successfully, and can be browsed without issue.

However, if I attempt to start a console (`bundle exec rails c`) after ssh'ing to the environment, I get the following:

```
Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

`bundle list` gives me all of the installed gems:

```
  * CFPropertyList (2.3.3)
  * RedCloth (4.2.9)
  .
  . (removed to allow it to fit into the question character limit)
  .
  * will_paginate-bootstrap (1.0.1)
  * xml-simple (1.1.5)
  * xpath (2.0.0)
```

`bundle env` gives me the following:

````
```
Bundler       1.16.2
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby          2.3.8p459 (2018-10-18 revision 65136) [x86_64-linux]
  Full Path   /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/etc
RubyGems      2.7.7
  Gem Home    /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.3.8
  Gem Path    /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.3.8:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  User Path   /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  Bin Dir     /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.3.8/bin
Tools         
  Git         2.14.5
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       not installed
  chruby      0.3.9
```

## Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2019-01-19
Git SHA           
Released Version  false
```

## Bundler settings

```
without
  Set for your local app (/var/app/current/.bundle/config): [:test, :development]
  Set via BUNDLE_WITHOUT: [:test, :development]
disable_shared_gems
  Set via BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: true
path
  Set via BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle"
```

## Gemfile

### Gemfile

```ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.0'
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'sprockets-es6', '~> 0.9.2'

  .
  . (removed to allow it to fit into the question character limit)
  .
PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  RedCloth (~> 4.2.3)
  active_scaffold!
  activemodel
  activerecord-session_store
  acts-as-taggable-on (~> 4.0)
  awesomemailer!
  axlsx!
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  bootstrap-editable-rails
  bootstrap-growl-rails
  bundler (>= 1.13.6)
  byebug
  calendar_date_select
  capybara
  carrierwave
  coffee-rails
  cucumber-rails
  daemons (= 1.1.0)
  database_cleaner
  decent_exposure
  delayed_job_active_record
  delayed_job_groups_plugin
  dynamic_form
  email_spec
  exception_notification
  factory_girl
  factory_girl_rails
  faker
  fog
  font-awesome-rails (~> 4.5)
  geokit-rails
  haml-rails
  html2haml
  icalendar
  inky-rb
  intercom-rails
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  less-rails (~> 3.0.0)
  less-rails-bootstrap!
  letter_opener
  mini_magick
  mocha
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.0)
  name_splitter
  newrelic_rpm
  omniauth-stripe-connect
  page_title_helper
  paperclip (~> 4.3)
  pickle
  plivo
  powder
  premailer-rails
  protected_attributes
  puma
  rack (= 1.6.10)
  rails (~> 4.2.0)
  rails-dom-testing
  rails-i18n (~> 4.0.0)
  rails-jquery-autocomplete
  rails-observers
  rails_autolink
  rake
  rb-readline
  recaptcha
  redactor2_rails
  responders
  rmagick
  rspec-collection_matchers
  rspec-expectations
  rspec-html-matchers
  rspec-rails (~> 3.1)
  rspec-rails-mocha!
  rspec-retry
  rspec_junit_formatter
  rubyzip
  sanitize_email
  sass-rails
  search_cop!
  selenium-webdriver
  sendgrid
  sendgrid-ruby
  shoulda
  shoulda-matchers
  simple_form
  skylight
  spring
  spring-commands-rspec
  sprockets-es6 (~> 0.9.2)
  squeel
  stripe
  stripe-ruby-mock (~> 2.5.0)
  syntax
  therubyracer
  thin
  timecop (= 0.3.5)
  truncate_html
  uglifier
  unicorn
  validates_timeliness (~> 3.0.2)
  will_paginate (~> 3.0)
  will_paginate-bootstrap
  xray-rails

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.1
```
````

And I can successfully run rake tasks: `bundle exec rake cron:create_remittance_records`

Using the same Gemfile and Gemfile.lock and a new rails 4.2.11 deployed using the same settings at AWS I am able to run `bundle exec rails c`, so it must be something in my application, but I am at a loss as to what could be effecting rails ability to load gems.

AWS support has also not been able to figure out the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you sshd in and run bundle check? Does it say the gemfile dependencies.have been satisfied? Also, have you tried with a newer version of bundler? How did you build Ruby? (Env seems to say not using rvm or rbenv)

Comment: Thanks for your comments @JayDorsey. `bundle check` indicates all dependencies are satisfied. I have not tried with a different version of bundler, but will do that today. Ruby is installed by AWS when it builds the ruby beanstalk instance. It asks what version of ruby you want to use and installs it. `which ruby` returns "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/bin/ruby".

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't upgrade Bundler to 2.* because Rails 4.2.11 requires Bundler < 2.0, and 1.16.1 is the latest version of bundler before 2.0. I could downgrade bundler, but I would just be shooting in the dark on which version. If you have a suggesting to a previous version that makes sense, please let me know.

Comment: 1.17.3 should be the latest < 2 version. Can you post your full Gemfile?

Comment: @JayDorsey - I have discovered the issue. I have a Gemfile group called :cucumber that is used when running Cucumber tests. `gem 'spring'` was listed in this group. My BUNDLE_WITHOUT env variable was set to 'development test'. So the spring gem was being installed and loaded. But because of this change ( https://github.com/rails/spring/pull/546), Spring is not honoring environment variables. 
Once I added :cucumber to the list of BUNDLE_WITHOUT groups, all started working as expected.

Comment: And, you are correct about the Bundler version. Not sure how I missed 1.17.3